# Use annotation to call a function

Tags: java, annotations

I am making an android app in which I have a function. I want to use annotation to call this.
My function is something like

```
public static void fn(String s1, String s2, double val) {
    //do something
}
```

Is there a way such that I can call this function with an annotation.
For example `@callFunc`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small example. I use annotation `@Replace` for replace non-alphanumeric character in `Employee` fields which marked by annotation `@Replace`. I hope it can help:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Employee employee = new Employee("Nguyen#@ Nhat^& Hoang<>");

    replace(employee);

    System.out.println(employee.getName());
}

public static void replace(Employee employee) {
    Field[] fields = employee.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        Replace replace =  fields[i].getAnnotation(Replace.class);
        if (replace != null) {
            try {
                fields[i].setAccessible(true);
                if (fields[i].get(employee) != null) {
                    fields[i].set(employee, String.valueOf(fields[i].get(employee)).replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", ""));
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Target(value = ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Replace {
}

public static class Employee {
    @Replace
    private String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, an annotation is declared as an `@interface` such as...

```
@interface ClassPreamble {
   String author();
   String date();
   int currentRevision() default 1;
   String lastModified() default "N/A";
   String lastModifiedBy() default "N/A";
   // Note use of array
   String[] reviewers();
}

@ClassPreamble (
   author = "John Doe",
   date = "3/17/2002",
   currentRevision = 6,
   lastModified = "4/12/2004",
   lastModifiedBy = "Jane Doe",
   // Note array notation
   reviewers = {"Alice", "Bob", "Cindy"}
)
public class Generation3List extends Generation2List {

// class code goes here

}
```

They have no implementation to call a method.  The only way you'd be able to do this would be to annotate your method and use reflection, then during the reflection parse the annotation and then call this method based on the reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of a method annotation (`@Example`) and AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) or AspectJ to create a proxy around the methods annotated with `@Example`. In this proxy, you can execute your code before or after the annotated method is called.